# Add outside collaborator to organization repository using github cli

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli

I am using [gh-cli](https://github.com/cli/cli)

I want to add outside collaborator to private repository (`my-repo-in-org`) in my organization(`my-org`)

I can display collaborators using this `gh`

```sh
gh api repos/my-org/myrepo-in-org/collaborators
```

Based on docs [Add a repository collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#add-a-repository-collaborator)
I tried to add collaborator (`collaborator_name`) with `push` permission using:

```sh
gh api repos/my-org/my-repo-in-org/collaborators/collaborator-name -f '{"permission"="push"}'
```

But getting:

```sh
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
gh: Not Found (HTTP 404)
```

Any clue how can I do it?
I need to manage multiple repositories with multiple users and want to automate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default http method used when you specify a parameter using `-f/--raw-field` is `POST` but this call requires `PUT` method. You can tell gh to specify the method using `-X` or `--method` :

```sh
gh api repos/{owner}/{repo}/collaborators/{username} -X PUT -f permission='push'
```

From the [documentation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) :

> The default HTTP request method is "GET" normally and "POST" if any
> parameters were added. Override the method with '--method'.

And in options list :

```
-X, --method string           The HTTP method for the request (default "GET")
```

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand Martel it works. 
-X Put was something that i missed.

Comment: I had to use `-F permission=read` because `-f permission=read` would be ignored.